# Need to replace deck post, flush with home foundation

Tags: deck, support, decking

I'm planning to replace a number of deck posts. Currently, my deck posts all go straight into the ground. For the posts I replace, I want to pour concrete footings. However, one of the posts is right next to our home's foundation. There is probably a centimeter of space between the foundation and the post. This makes pouring a footer difficult, for obvious reason. Any ideas on how I should approach this?

I'd prefer to avoid a major modifications to the structure of the deck. The deck is 20'x20' and uses 9 6'x6' posts for support.

Comment: Photos would help